# Multiples fuentes personalizadas, una no funciona

Tags: css, fuentes

Tengo multiples fuentes agregadas con css en una pagina, pero una de ellas (Monserrat Bold) no se ve reflejada como se podra ver en las imagenes

Se deberia de ver con en la parte de arriba de la imagen pero aparece

[image: Se deberia de ver como en la parte de arriba]

aqui el codigo css que tengo

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'Monserrat';
  src: url('/Resources/Fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.otf');
  src: url('Resources/Fonts/Montserrat/._Montserrat-Black.otf');

}
@font-face{
  font-family: 'MonserratBold' ;
  src: url('Resources/Fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.otf');
}
@font-face{
  font-family: 'MonserratMed';
  src: url('Resources/Fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Medium.otf');

}
```

Saben cual puede ser el error?
Debido a que si toma el font family de Monsserrat y de MonserratMed

Comment: ¿Verificaste que los archivos están en la carpeta `Fonts/Montserrat` tal y como los tienes escritos en CSS, y que no están protegidos por permisos especiales de lectura? Además, es extraño que en unas tienes escrito `Monserrat` y en otras `Montserrat`. **¿Con `t` o sin `t` intermedia?**

Comment: En cualquier caso, yo las incluiría desde [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?selection.family=Montserrat), descargando así mi servidor.

Comment: Tendrías que general un webkit para cada tipo de letra, no importa si es la misma, pero hay que declararlas. Utiliza fontsquirrel para generar tu webkit de letra regular, black, bold, y medium... Cada fontkit genera distintos tipos de archivos... esos son los que debes agregar para que funcione correctamente la font-family